# Reading urls from CSV, Get HTTP Response Status, Check for Redirect, Store in new CSV

Tags: python, csv, python-requests

I have a csv file that has a bunch of urls in it.  I am working on a script that does the following:

1. Read urls in from the csv
2. Pass url list to request.get() 
   and then
3. Get initial http status along with the redirected url and http status

My code works fine when I only pass in a single url and don't  try and read the urls from another csv. However at scale it makes the most sense to read bulk urls from a file and then process the output to another file.  Can you please help me understand where my code is breaking down?  Thanks in advance.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
import csv
import time

# set filename with date + time
timestr = time.strftime("%m-%d-%Y-%H-%M-%S")
filename = str("redirect-output\\redirect-test-"+timestr+".csv")

with open('bulk-url-filename.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        urls = row[0]
        #print urls
        r = requests.get(urls)

f = open(filename, 'a+')
response = requests.get(r)
if response.history:
    print "Request was redirected:"
    reqredirected = "Request was redirected:"
    f.write(reqredirected)
    f.write("\n")
    for resp in response.history:
        print resp.status_code
        status = str(resp.status_code)
        f.write(status)
        f.write("\n")
        print resp.url
        url = str(resp.url)
        f.write(url)
        f.write("\n")
    print "Final destination:"
    final = "Final destination:"
    f.write(final)
    f.write("\n")
    print response.status_code
    destinationstatus = str(response.status_code)
    f.write(destinationstatus)
    f.write("\n")
    print response.url
    destinationurl = str(response.url)
    f.write(destinationurl)
    print "\n"
    f.write("\n")
else:
    print "Request was not redirected"
    noredirect = "Request was not redirected"
    f.write(noredirect)
    f.write("\n")
    responseurl = response.url
    print responseurl
    f.write(responseurl)
    f.write("\n")
```

I am printing output to the console so I can see what is happening as well as writing lines into the csv for later analysis.

Comment: Can you fix the indentation in your code? As it is it won't run and it is a little hard to tell where your issues may be.

Comment: Why do you have this line `response = requests.get(r)` when `r` is already a response? Also based on your current indentation, `r` is assigned to every time through the loop and nothing is done with it.

Comment: fixed indentation.  The `response = requests.get(r)` line was from the initial implementation and when I was attempting to expand on the code to allow for urls from a separate csv to be read into the script, that is where the `r = requests.get(urls)` code came from.  I just wasn't sure how to merge the two ideas cohesively.

Comment: I found a solution to my issue.  I renamed the `r= requests.get(urls)` to `response=requests.get(url)` and moved the blocks of code under the `with open('file.csv','rb' as f:` line of code and now the script runs as intended.  thanks